# Difference responses in SQL request and Link request using BLToolkit

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, bltoolkit

I am using BLToolkit and find out an interesting behaviour. I don't understand why using the same request in link give me different results:
SQL request:

---

```
select TOP 1 * from table where  coverCode='1+4' 
                                             and effectiveDate <='20130103' 
                                              and  maxValue >= '1000'  
                                             order by maxValue asc, effectivedate desc
```

---

this table actually has two  results:

- A)  (id): 1ffbe215-ff0e-47dd-9718-4130ffb62539  (maxValue): 1000
    (effDate):2011-01-01   (price):40
- B)  (id): b787a74e-696b-493d-a4bc-5bb407e231b3     (maxValue):1000
    (effDate):2011-01-01       (price):80

and SQL request gives me the A result.
and at the same time the request using Linq:

```
db.Rate
   .Where(x=>x.coverCode == "1+4"
           && x.effectiveDate <= '20130103'
            && x.MaxValue >= '1000')
            .OrderBy(x => x.MaxValue)
            .ThenByDescending(x => x.effectiveDate)
```

This request gives me the B result.
Can anyone explain why or what is wrong in the linq request?

Comment: The LINQ code would not compile. Please show us the actual code that you executed.

Comment: Also, please post the generated SQL which you can catch by running SQL Profiler.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to inspect your `db.LastQuery` right after your LINQ code executed. You'll see the generated SQL, and you can compare it with the one you really wanted.